# QuickBlox SDK for codenameone

Tags: quickblox

Is there a client SDK for QuickBlox in codenameone? I am trying to build a cross platform chat application using Codenameone and QuickBlox. Codenameone of course does not use the standard java/android SDK and I don't have the skills to do a native client. Is there a Codenameone port of the QuickBlox SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it wasn't adapted. It isn't very hard to port an SDK but it does require dealing with native code. My only suggestion is to hire someone or upgrade to enterprise and file an official request for that SDK

Comment: Must it be the enterprise only? How do I find someone to build for me? Any reference site for codenameone developers?

Comment: I can't really tell if someone can do this and for how much. The SDK is pretty big so this will require some work to map out the API's. The reason we ask for an enterprise license is that it's really hard for us to define priorities with users asking for things all the time. When someone pays for something that mean that person is serious and we take the request seriously